# Regex - finding optional arguments

Tags: regex

I would like to write a regex to extract arguments and operation sign if given or just extract a value in a given formula.

```
 "=400/500"   will find 400, /, and 500
 "=400"       will find 400
```

So far I tried with group matching approach and a regex like following:

```
 =(.*)(/|\*|\+|-)(.*)
```

However, that does not work in all cases. For example, I get following:

```
 "=400/500"   will find 400, /, and 500 which is exactly what I need
 "=400"       does not find any matches and I expect to get 400
```

I tried some modifications to my script but so far without any success.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 =(.*)(\/)(.*)|=(.*)
```

if you are going with the any chr wild cards with an "/" deliminator

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is a very generic solution and will work well even in cases like this:

    Input: "=[$arg1]/arg2"        Result:   0: [0,13] =[$arg1]/arg2
                                                            1: [1,8] [$arg1]
                                                            2: [8,9] /
                                                            3: [9,13] arg2
                                                            4: [-1,-1] null

Which is mighty when formulae have alphanumeric arguments. I like it too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simplest one, Hope this will be helpful. You can add `()` at different places to capture all matches in different groups.

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/J2SS8H/2)

**Regex:** `\d+[+*\/-]?\d+`

> **1.** `[+*\/-]?` match for `+`, `-`, `/`, and `*` any of these operations, and `?` makes it optional.
>
> **2.** `\d+` This will match digits one or more digits.

Comment: I dont think he want to exclude the mathematical op. as he said in his question he need to match it not to exclude, or i misunderstand his question ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this one ? I assumed that it will be digits only.

```
=\d+[+\-*\/]?\d+
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/grbLYH/11)

If you would like to use grouping:

```
=(\d+)([+\-*\/])?(\d+)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/grbLYH/13)

Remove `=` if you dont want to match it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to (.*) who responded :-)

Your answers were very quick and insightful. I was not 100% clear in my original question, hence people provided different solutions. I wanted to utilize regex group searching. Expressions are mainly formulae or assignment operation. For example:

```
=500          // want to get 500 and understand there is no operator
=500+34       // want to get 500 and 34 and understand the operation is addition
=500/100      // want to get 500 and 100 and understand the operation is division
=500-100      //...
=500*100
```

That way I can easily extract arguments and operator or just a value in case there is no operator. I settled with modified Sahil's answer. For example, now I am using the following:

```
=(\d+)([+*\/-])?(\d+)?
```

These are results for the following inputs:

```
Input string: "=400/500"      Result:   0: [0,8] =400/500
                                        1: [1,4] 400
                                        2: [4,5] /
                                        3: [5,8] 500

Input string: "=500"          Result:   0: [0,4] =500
                                        1: [1,4] 500
                                        2: [-1,-1] null
                                        3: [-1,-1] null

Input string: "=400/"         Result:   0: [0,5] =400/
                                        1: [1,4] 400
                                        2: [4,5] /
                                        3: [-1,-1] null
```

If I use regex this way based on a number of groups found I can easily figure out type of formula used and therefore extract all the values provided in groups.